# Greek vowels with accents shown as two characters instead of a single one

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I am handling input in **Greek** language, where vowels can have **accents**.

I noticed some strange input in words that contain vowels with accents, sometimes the same vowel with accent seems to be **two separate characters** while other times the same vowel with accent seems to be **one character**, I guess a **different charset encoding** is guilty about that behaviour.

Example shown below

**έ** -----> is two separate characters, **ε** and the **́**

**έ** -----> is a single character **έ**

My **questions** regarding the behaviour described above are the following:

1. What is the **root cause** of this phenomenon?
2. How could I possibly convert all these **two characters** toned vowels into **single character** toned vowel? (for example convert έ into έ), is there any "global way" to deal with that kind of encoding problems?

Currently as a solution what I do is **replace any possible two characters vowel into single character** as following:

```
text = text.replaceAll("ά", "ά")
        .replaceAll("έ", "έ")
        .replaceAll("ή", "ή")
        .replaceAll("ί", "ί")
        .replaceAll("ύ", "ύ")
        .replaceAll("ό", "ό")
        .replaceAll("ώ", "ώ")
        .replaceAll("Ά", "Ά")
        .replaceAll("Έ", "Έ")
        .replaceAll("Ή", "Ή")
        .replaceAll("Ί", "Ί")
        .replaceAll("Ύ", "Ύ")
        .replaceAll("Ό", "Ό")
        .replaceAll("Ώ", "Ώ");
```

but There should be a better way to achieve that, I use **Java** for this text handling

Comment: See [java.text.Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html).

Comment: Regarding the root cause, there's some information here on how the Greek encodings got to be that way: https://www.unicode.org/faq/greek.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause: Sometime there is many different ways to represent the same glyph with Unicode. Usually we convert to a canonical form, but there is two canonical/normalization form (decomposed: NFD and composed: NFC). Apple prefers the first (and it was the original prefered way of Unicode), most of the other operating systems prefer the second. And each font has own preference (but shaper library will handle it).

You can transform your text into the canonical composed form (NFC), but not all glyphs can be transformed into one single characters: some combination of accent and base character requires two codepoints (or more if you have multiple accents).

Comment: @Sweeper: oops. I got too many answers, and I confused the right tab.

Comment: Thanks for your illustrative answer! Indeed the `NFD` normalized text came from an apple system while the others from Windows systems

Answer (score 5):

Due to the complexity of Unicode, there are multiple ways of encoding the same text. You can encode ε with an acute accent as the single character "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON WITH TONOS" (U+03AD), or as "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON" (U+03B5) followed by "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" (U+0301). And different people and software *do* encode these differently sometimes.

To convert to the "more compact" encoding, you can use the [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) class, and [Normalisation Form](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) C (NFC).

```
// you can pass the entire string into this:
Normalizer.normalize("ε\u0301", Normalizer.Form.NFC) // produces a string with a \u03AD char
```

The less compact encoding is called NFD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed I used `Normalizer.normalize("έ", Normalizer.Form.NFC)` which transformed my string into `NFC` format, I wish I could accept both of the answers :)